# A spin game monte carlo

Tags: python, montecarlo

Problem:

Here’s a little Monte Carlo challenge problem, Consider the following game, which uses the two spinner disks. Suppose a player spins one or the other of the pointers on the disks according to the following rules:

1. if the player spins pointer i and it stops in the region with area `p_{ij}`, he moves from disk `i` to disk `j` (`i` and `j` are either 1 or 2);
2. if a pointer stops in the region with area `x_i`, the game ends;
3. if the game ends in the region with area `x_1`, the player wins, but if the pointer stops in the region with area `x_2` the player loses.

What is the probability the player, starting with disk 1, wins? Assume the area of each disk is one, so that `x_1+p_{11}+p_{12} =1`, as well as that `x_2+p_{21}+p_{22} =1`

Run your code for the case of `p_{11} =0.2`, `p_{12} =0.4`, `p_{21} =0.3`, and `p_{22} =0.35`.

```
import random
p_11 = 0.2
p_12 = 0.4 #0.2+0.4
p_21 = 0.3
p_22 = 0.35


wins = 0
pointer = 0
pointer2 = 0
for i in range(10**7):
    while pointer < p_11:
        pointer2 = 0    #resetting pointer2
        pointer = random.uniform(0,1)
        if p_11+p_21  < pointer < 1:  #area corresponding to x_1
            wins += 1  #wins
            pointer = 0  
            break
        else:
            pointer = 0  #resetting pointer1
            while pointer2 < p_22:
                pointer2 = random.uniform(0,1)
                if p_22+p_21 < pointer2 < 1:  #area corresponding to x_2
                    pointer2 = 0
                    break  #loses

print(wins/10**7)
```

The correct answer is 0.5821 however I am getting 0.7141465.  Where am I doing wrong ?

I edited my code, in this case it turns the disk again for  `p_22` and  `p_11` cases

[image]

The question is from the book called Digital Dice (Paul J. Nahim) Page 27-29 (Theres a pdf )

Comment: Why all the downvotes? They state the problem, give relevant background, show a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, and even give the current/expected outputs.

Comment: These rules are really hard to understand. What is area `pij`? What is `xi` in "region with area xi"? Is that `X1`? or `P_11`?. Is it significant that `(i and j are either 1 or 2)`?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong @Rear.
Disk1 Region 1 (x1): Land on this and you win. ---
Disk1 Region 2 (p11): Land on this and spin disk1 again. ---
Disk1 Region 3 (p12): Land on this and switch to disk 2, then spin disk 2. ---

Disk2 Region 1 (x2): Land on this and you lose. ---
Disk2 Region 2 (p21): Land on this and switch to disk 1, then spin disk 1. ---
Disk2 Region 3 (p22): Land on this and spin disk2 again. ---

Comment: I'm guessing there should be a diagram? Is this a coding challenge site or homework? Are you sure P_1 and P_2 are correctly calculated? Have you tried adding up losses and see if wins + losses add up to 10**7? I don't see anything here for spins on disk 2.

Comment: I put a diagram and edited my post a bit. I hope this helps more..Its not homework or a coding challange site. Its just from a book that I am reading to learn monte carlo algorithm. Well I didnt get to the part for what happens if it stars from disk2.

Comment: Yes the rules are hard to understand indeed but I just copied from the book. I guess you are right @SytaxVoid. I get also confused about the part that what happens when we land on p_22 or p_11 I thought that in these parts as well we will change our disk. But I guess we will not

Comment: The book has no information on that topic. But I think its from always 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have analyzed the problem mathematically and found out that the solution is actually:

`(1 - p_11 - p_12) * (1 - p_22) / ((1 - p_11) * (1 - p_22) - p_12 * p_21)` (which is actually not correct in some corner cases (e.g. `p_22 = 1`))

This is actually written in Appendix 6 of the Digital Dice book, so I won't prove it.

With your numbers it gives the answer of `0.65` and that is correct. Your code changed a lot and now it gives the output of `1.0` instead of what is written in the question. Here I corrected the first version of your code:

```
import random


p_11 = 0.2
p_12 = 0.4
p_21 = 0.3
p_22 = 0.35

total_iterations = 10 ** 6

wins = 0
num = 0
for i in range(total_iterations):
    current_disk = 1
    while True:
        num = random.uniform(0, 1)
        if current_disk == 1:
            if num < p_12:
                current_disk = 2
                continue
            elif num > p_11 + p_12:
                wins += 1  #wins
                break
        else:
            if num < p_21:
                current_disk = 1
                continue
            elif num > p_21 + p_22:
                break

print(wins / total_iterations)
print((1 - p_11 - p_12) * (1 - p_22) / ((1 - p_11) * (1 - p_22) - p_12 * p_21))
```

Now about your current code. It is wrong now because `break # loses` breaks from the loop `while pointer2 < p_22`, not from the loop `while pointer < p_11`. We can fix it by adding extra flag `lost` and that will give you correct answer.

```
import random
p_11 = 0.2
p_12 = 0.4 #0.2+0.4
p_21 = 0.3
p_22 = 0.35


wins = 0
pointer = 0
pointer2 = 0
for i in range(10**6):
    while pointer < p_11:
        pointer2 = 0    #resetting pointer2
        pointer = random.uniform(0,1)
        if p_11+p_21  < pointer < 1:  #area corresponding to x_1
            wins += 1  #wins
            pointer = 0  
            break
        else:
            pointer = 0  #resetting pointer1
            lost = False
            while pointer2 < p_22:
                pointer2 = random.uniform(0,1)
                if p_22+p_21 < pointer2 < 1:  #area corresponding to x_2
                    pointer2 = 0
                    lost = True
                    break  #loses
            if lost:
                break

print(wins/10**6)
```

Comment: wait so the theres something wrong in the text (book) but not in my code ?

Comment: My first code was assuming that if the pointer lands on p_11 or p_12 the disk will change but that cannot be true, right ? In my second code I assumed that on p_11 or on p_22, the disk will rotate again. Now thinking they are mathematically same. Theres always two possibllites, even we turn the disk again, it will again either go to the disk2 or we will win, so my original code was right. Thanks then

Comment: There's actually nothing wrong in the book. It is written that the answer is `0.65` in the book (page 245)

Comment: Thats great. I have the actual book and there it says 0.5821. Its not my mistake...I can even send a photo but that would be unnecessary I think

Comment: About your second commentary. Of course, it is NOT true that it if pointer lands to `p_11` the disk will change. All your commentaries about your second code seems right.

Comment: @Rear I think that's because I found 2nd Edition (2013) with some mistakes fixed.